Only trigger workflow if it is coming from a specific branch
Given the following branches:

main
feature_1
feature_important_1
feature_2
feature_3
feature_important_2
feature_4

To trigger pipelines from any branch to branches named *_important_*, we can use:
name: "some_name"
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - '*_important_*'

But what I want to do is only trigger on branches named *important* that go to main,
how can I filter on the branch "source" name on pull request?
e.g.
name: "some_name"
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - 'main'
    source_branches: # THIS PART  IS MADE UP
      - '*_important_*'


https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore is for the base, if you want to filter based on the head then set branches: [ main ] and then check which branch it's from, based on the github context, to conditionally run the relevant job.

@jonrsharpe by filtering in job wouldnt that mean that the workflow is still started, i do not want to start the workflow at all, to avoid pollution.

I don't know what "pollution" you're concerned about, but again the trigger filtering is for the base branch.

@jonrsharpe thanks I got the part about the filter being for the base. With pollution I ment, the workflow is still started, and in the workflow runs it will show up. Thanks for the comment though. I want to avoid running the workflow at all. Lets say we have a few hundred branches and I only want to use it on 3,

This controls whether the workflow starts, but currently only the base branch can be excluded from the PR, and branch to the main cannot.
This means that based on your limitations, it will start, perhaps it's the pollution you mentioned.
Of course, it can be skipped through if and context. And please note that it can only be skipped.
jobs:
  specific-branch:
    if: github.head_ref == 'test'

